# How to merge 2 similar queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables like this:

#### people

```
id_p    name      email         phone
------------------------------------------
1       Wanda     a@a.a     +123
2       Vision    b@b.b     +234
3       Falcon    c@c.c     +345
4       Winter S  d@d.d     +456
```

#### lecturers

```
id_a    id_p     department     field          id_institution
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       1        Enginering     Electronics    4
2       2        Life Science   Psychology     12
```

#### students

```
id_b    id_p       major        field      id_institution
-------------------------------------------------------
1       3          Computer     Robotic    1
2       4          Computer     AI         5
```

I want to JOIN this to table to another table, this is query to get student:

```
SELECT people.* , student.major, student.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN student ON student.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.major = student.major
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = student.id_institution
```

I wanna get the lecturer to, this is my query:

```
SELECT people.* , lecturer.department, lecturer.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN lecturer ON lecturer.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.departmen = lecturer.department
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = lecturer.id_institution
```

These 2 queries is similiar. My real query is more complex than these queries, and have sub-queries. I use DataTable server-side because there is more than 10000 data to processed. But, even in server-side, it still take long time, and I think it is happend because there is two complex queries to be executed.

How to merge these 2 smiliar queries?

Comment: What relationship do lecturers have to students, in this context? "It looks similar" or "They both have 3 string columns" is not really sufficient justification to combine queries

Comment: Is there perhaps a `class` table and/or a `class_enrollment` table? As it is there doesn't appear a way to related students to lecturers in any meaningful way.

Comment: @CaiusJard There is no relationship of lecturers and students. I just wanna get all people data, but it have to use 2 queries because there is different collumn name in student and lecturer. I asking is there is possible to di it?

Comment: [Anything is possible](https://imgflip.com/i/2caj3o)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`union all`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```sql
SELECT people.* , student.major, student.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN student ON student.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.major = student.major
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = student.id_institution

union all 

SELECT people.* , lecturer.department, lecturer.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN lecturer ON lecturer.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.departmen = lecturer.department
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = lecturer.id_institution
```

But you will no longer see the difference between a `lecturer` and a `student`, so you might need to add this column:

```sql
SELECT 'student' as fromtable, people.* , student.major, student.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN student ON student.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.major = student.major
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = student.id_institution

union all 

SELECT 'lecturer', people.* , lecturer.department, lecturer.field, another_table.some, another_table2.some FROM people
LEFT JOIN lecturer ON lecturer.id_p = people.id_p
LEFT JOIN another_table ON another_table.departmen = lecturer.department
LEFT JOIN another_table2 ON another_table2.id_institution = lecturer.id_institution
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i finally search for the way to do it, and found it [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/724039), where it says: "Double quotes are supported by MySQL for string values as well, but single quotes are more widely accepted by other RDBMS, so it is a good habit to use single quotes instead of double."